# как правильно сделать TryParse enum списка?

Tags: c#

как правильно проверить через enum tryparse чтоб если вводилось неправильная еда срабатывал Default не могу понять как сделать через трайпарс

```
namespace ex14;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int satietyLevel = 0;
        Console.WriteLine($"текущий уровень сытости кота {satietyLevel}");
        Console.WriteLine("Hey don't forget to feed your cat \n" +
                       "What will you feed your cat\n" + "Milk\n" + "Water\n" + "Beef\n" + "Chiken\n" +
                       "Kitekat\n");      
        string operation = Console.ReadLine();
        Food eat = (Food)Enum.Parse(typeof(Food), operation);
        Operation(eat); 
    } 
    static void Operation(Food Oper)
    {
        
        Food kitekat = Food.Kitekat;
        Food water = Food.Water;
        Food milk = Food.Milk;
        Food beef = Food.Beef;
        Food chiken = Food.Chiken;
        switch (Oper)
            {
                case Food.Kitekat:
                    Console.WriteLine("Cat ate  kitekat, satiety level =  {0} ", (int)kitekat);
                    break;
                case Food.Water:
                    Console.WriteLine("Cat drank water satiety level = {0}", (int)water);
                    break;
                case Food.Milk:
                    Console.WriteLine("Cat drank  milk, satiety level = {0}", (int)milk);
                    break;
                case Food.Beef:
                    Console.WriteLine("Cat ate Beef, satiety level = {0}", (int)beef);
                    break;
                case Food.Chiken:
                    Console.WriteLine("Cat ate chiken , satiety level = {0}", (int)chiken);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Wrong food");
                    break;
            }
    }
}

public enum Food
{
    Milk = 20,
    Water = 30,
    Beef = 100, 
    Chiken = 70, 
    Kitekat = 50, 
    
}
```

Comment: Вероятно надо добавить operation = "Food." + operation. С дефолтом: if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TEnum), strEnumValue))
        return defaultValue;

    return (TEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(TEnum), strEnumValue);

Comment: Не могли бы показать как сделать в коде а то не совсем понятно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (Enum.TryParse(operation, out Food eat))
{
    Operation(eat);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Wrong food");
}
```

Кстати вот это `(Food)Enum.Parse(typeof(Food), operation)` можно было написать проще `Enum.Parse<Food>(operation)`

А вот это `(int)kitekat` можно без лишних переменных вот так `(int)Oper`.

Comment: Все равно не могу понять куда это надо вставить вставляю в метод мейн и он не работает

Comment: @cloudywhiteen вместо строчки `Food eat = ` и следующей за ней.

Comment: спасибо за ответ извиняюсь за свою тупость уже поздно сидел решал уже спать хочу XD

Comment: @cloudywhiteen ничего, все мы когда-то учились и тупили

Answer (score 0):

Такой вариант:

```
public static T ToEnum<T>(this string strEnumValue, T defaultValue, bool ignoreCase=true)  where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) 
        throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enumerated type");

    if (!Enum.IsDefined<T>((object)strEnumValue))
        return defaultValue;

    return Enum.Parse<T>(strEnumValue, ignoreCase); // тут стринг
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse тогда зачем придуман? `Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Food), strEnumValue)` не скомпилится или всегда false, потому что `string` != `Food`

Comment: Я же написал Вариант :) TryParse - уже показали :)

Comment: @aepot C object должно собраться

Comment: Ну значит в рантайме упадет, в любом случае IsDefined со строками не работает, он для перечислений.

Comment: // Call IsDefined with string containing member name.
      value = "Rodent";
      Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", value, Enum.IsDefined(typeof(PetType), value)); - от мелко-мягких

Comment: `ToEnum<Food>` вообще странное что-то. Типа обобщение? Но зачем? Ну ок, допустим IsDefined выживет.

Comment: нет, это как List<int>() - задали тип , как шаблон в С++. В С# дженерик называется

Comment: Метод расширения человеку, который с трудом с if-else справляется вы тоже зря предлагаете.

Comment: Я знаю что такое дженерик и как с ним работать, но это точно не ваш случай. Здесь работа с конкретным перечислением.

Comment: Но если уж решили обобщение, то пишите `T` и добавьте ограничение `where T : struct, Enum`, иначе Enum.Parse не скомпилится.

Comment: `IConvertible` заменить на `Enum` и можно бужет убрать первую проверку. То чно можно ловить на этапе компиляции, лучше ловить на этапе компиляции, а не в рантайме

Comment: `Enum.Parse<T>` не принимает тип object. `Enum.IsDefined` не принимает тип object

Comment: Тут стринг надо и игноре кейс включил